# PostgreSQL insert performance - why would it be so slow?

Tags: postgresql, performance

I've got a PostgreSQL database running inside a docker container on an AWS Linux instance.  I've got some telemetry running, uploading records in batches of ten.  A Python server inserts these records into the database.  The table looks like this:

```
postgres=# \d raw_journey_data ;
                    Table "public.raw_journey_data"
 Column |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 email  | character varying           |           |          | 
 t      | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 lat    | numeric(20,18)              |           |          | 
 lng    | numeric(21,18)              |           |          | 
 speed  | numeric(21,18)              |           |          |
```

There aren't that many rows in the table; about 36,000 presently.  But committing the transactions that insert the data is taking about a minute each time:

```
postgres=# SELECT pid, age(clock_timestamp(), query_start), usename, query 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE query != '<IDLE>' AND query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%' 
ORDER BY query_start desc;
 pid |       age       | usename  | query  
-----+-----------------+----------+--------
  30 |                 |          | 
  32 |                 | postgres | 
  28 |                 |          | 
  27 |                 |          | 
  29 |                 |          | 
  37 | 00:00:11.439313 | postgres | COMMIT
  36 | 00:00:11.439565 | postgres | COMMIT
  39 | 00:00:36.454011 | postgres | COMMIT
  56 | 00:00:36.457828 | postgres | COMMIT
  61 | 00:00:56.474446 | postgres | COMMIT
  35 | 00:00:56.474647 | postgres | COMMIT
(11 rows)
```

The load average on the system's CPUs is zero and about half of the 4GB system RAM is available (as shown by `free`).  So what causes the super-slow commits here?

The insertion is being done with SqlAlchemy:

```
        db.session.execute(import_table.insert([
            {
                "email": current_user.email,
                "t": row.t.ToDatetime(),
                "lat": row.lat,
                "lng": row.lng,
                "speed": row.speed
            }
            for row in data.data
        ]))
```

**Edit** Update with the state column:

```
postgres=# SELECT pid, age(clock_timestamp(), query_start), usename, state, query 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%' 
ORDER BY query_start desc;
 pid |       age       | usename  | state | query  
-----+-----------------+----------+-------+--------
  32 |                 | postgres |       | 
  30 |                 |          |       | 
  28 |                 |          |       | 
  27 |                 |          |       | 
  29 |                 |          |       | 
  46 | 00:00:08.390177 | postgres | idle  | COMMIT
  49 | 00:00:08.390348 | postgres | idle  | COMMIT
  45 | 00:00:23.35249  | postgres | idle  | COMMIT
(8 rows)
```

Comment: First thing we would need to know is what the table looks like. Are the columns huge? Do you have a lot of indexing going on? We don't know what work is being done when you do the insert.

Comment: First thing I would try to figure out is if the slowdown is in Postgresql, or in Python talking to it. You need to know which side of the work is being slow. What if you do the insert with raw SQL? If it's slow there, then you know it's SQL that is at fault. If it's quick in raw SQL, but slow going through sqlalchemy, then you know it's in sqlalchemy somewhere.

Comment: @AndyLester - re your first point, the table description is in the question.

Comment: And @AndyLester - re your second point, it's the commit that's taking a long time.  How complicated can commit be on the Python side?

Comment: Though, to be fair, inserting records into the same table from `psql` does not see this issue.  Will investigate further.

Comment: So you have no indexes at all on the table?

Comment: "But committing the transactions that insert the data is taking about a minute each time"  That is a possible misinterpretation of what your query shows.  Try looking at the rest of the columns of pg_stat_activity.

Comment: @AndyLester No, no indices.  But does that justify a 1 minute commit with 36,000 rows?

Comment: @Tom No, lack of indexes would mean it would take *less* time to do the insert, so that's surprising.

Comment: Idle transactions are indicated with the string value `idle`, so your condition `!= '<IDLE>'` will return all sessions because there is no state that would equal `<IDLE>`. Older Postgres versions would actually use `<idle>` (lowercase!) but that is still different and I don't think any supported version still uses that. You should include the `state` column in your output

Comment: @AndyLester Thanks for your help, I've tracked this down to an unrelated firewall problem.  Not what I thought.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out! I'm curious how the firewall was causing the problem, if you don't mind sharing briefly.

Comment: Largely me getting confused.  The Python server has a connection to two databases.  One of the connections was being obstructed by the firewall in a way that caused an inordinately long timeout.  But I started looking at the other connection and found all these statements that were taking over a minute - not realising they were all in the idle state and that this meant they had actually completed.